# Swipe gesture from inside html page not working in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, html, ios, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView which loads an html page that supports swipe left/right gesture to switch between content. This gesture works well when the page is opened from a desktop browser but doesn't work at all when loaded from a UIWebView.

**jQuery Swipe**

FOR IPHONE & IPOD TOUCH MOBILE APPS

*iPhone and iPod Touch swipe gesture support using Safari JavaScript for onTouchStart, onTouchMove, onTouchEnd and onTouchCancel.
This plugin uses Mobile Safari's built in touch events to allow jQuery binding of swipe events to any DOM element. You can override the swipeLeft and swipeRight defaults functions to create your own custom process when the gesture is detected.*
This is the plugin used for swiping: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/swipe

Did anyone else had this issue?
Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

//For Left Swipe

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipeleft=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeleft)];
                    swipeleft.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
                    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeleft];
```

//For Right Swipe

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swiperight=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swiperight)];
                    swiperight.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
                    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swiperight];
```

Methods

```
-(void)swipeleft{
}
-(void)swiperight{        
}
```

Try this one..

Comment: Thanks but this swipe is for the UIWebView, not for the content of the webpage. This would mean to run js code from the swipe methods which is not an option. I would like the javascript swipe to work without using iOS Gesture Recognizers.